Are real-analytic functions in $\mathbb{R}^2$ holomorphic after suitable change of coordinates?
I'm not sure this is a research-level question, but I couldn't find an answer after a bit of searching, so here goes.
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a real-analytic function. Can we always find a Riemann surface $M$ and a real-analytic injective "change of coordinates" $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to M$, such that $\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is holomorphic on $\mathrm{Im}~\phi$? If not, what are necessary and sufficient conditions for this to be the case?
If that is relevant, in my particular case $f$ is also injective, so answers conditional to that are also welcome.

$(x,y) \mapsto (x,0)$ might be a counterexample for the non-objective case.

What does it mean for the function ∘f∘^(-1) to be holomorphic "on Im " ?  I don't understand what "on Im " means in this context.

@DanielAsimov the intention was that $\phi$ may not generically be surjective on $M$, so $\phi^{-1}$ may only be defined on some domain (i'm not sure whether assuming surjectiveness would limit generality or not).

Ohhhhhhhhh, I think I see now that the notation "Im " is meant to indicate the image of the map .  I was confused because the notation "Im f" — especially in the context of complex variables — always means "the imaginary part of f". So if f(z) = u(z) + iv(z) with u, v real, then Im(f) = v.

May  I  suggest that you  add the tag  Dynamical  system  to  your  question?

The answer is negative. For the non-injective case, the reason is that non-constant complex analytic functions are open, discrete maps, while real analytic functions can be neither open nor discrete (see the comment to the question). So you cannot make $f$ complex analytic even by a transformation $\psi\circ f\circ\phi$, where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are distinct.
For the injective case, take $f$ such that $f(0)=0$, and
consider the Jacobi matrix $J_f(0)$. Then $J_{\phi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}}=J_\phi J_f J_\phi^{-1}$ by the chain rule, and Jacobi matrices of
complex analytic maps are conformal (that is orthogonal with determinant $1$ times positive scalar, while for general real
analytic maps they don't have this property.
In particular, two eigenvalues of $J_f$ have equal moduli.
So, for example, the map $(x,y)\mapsto (2x,y)$
cannot be conjugate to a complex analytic function.
It will not help if you allow $\phi$ to be non-differentiable (just a local homeomorphism), since in
the example above the map $f$ has a curve of fixed points, while for complex analytic maps (other than identity) fixed points are isolated.

Thank you, these are good points. I don't quite follow the chain rule argument, shouldn't it be $J_{\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}} = J_{\phi} J_f (J_{\phi})^{-1}$? While it's true that $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is not a conjugate of an orthogonal matrix, a non-orthogonal $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is conjugate to a reflection rotated by $2\pi/3$.

I'm still curious if there are deeper necessary conditions than some good behaviour near fixed points, as well their isolatedness.

@MikhailTikhomirov  Yes I  agree that the  conjugate of a  complex  matrix is  not  necessarily a  complex  matrix.

@MikhailTikhomirov  but $(x,y) \mapsto (x, -y)$ can not be  covered by a bioholomorphism since it is orientation reversing. In fact orientation, determinant, is preserved by conjugacy. Moreover  as it is  mentioned  by  in answer  and  comment by prof. Eremenko and  others the  fixed points  are not isolated, another obstruction

What about $2z$?

@Mikhail Tikhomirov: I corrected. Hope it is precise now.

@Mikhail Tikhomirov: on your second comment. The behaviour at a fixed point enters naturally, at least when we consider only local behavior. Otherwise, the difference between $\phi,\phi^{-1}$ and an arbitrary pair $(\phi,\psi)$ disappears.

Thank you for the correction! I still think that a conformal matrix can be conjugate to a non-conformal one, e.g. the negation of my example above.

Are you saying that an arbitrary pair $(\phi, \psi)$ can be reconciled into $(\phi, \phi^{-1})$ somehow? I don't quite see how to do it. The general problem is a functional Cauchy-Riemann PDE, which I can see breaking for all sorts of other reasons.

If $f(a)=b$, and $a\neq b$, then $a,b$ have disjoint neighborhoods. Now look at the domains of $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$. Two functions with disjoint domains can be always pasted into one function. What I am saying is that a LOCAL version of your question only makes sense in a neighborhood of a fixed point.

@Mikhail Tikhomirov: again on your second comment. There are "deeper reasons", of course. You can have a germ of a diffeomorphism near a fixed point, whose Jacobi matrix is conformal (say the unit matrix) but which is not conjugate to a holomorphic germ. Plenty of obstacles to such a conjugation is provided by local holomorphic dynamics.

@AlexandreEremenko  What  are some  more  obstacles? An  obstruction I  know is a possible  negative  Lefschetz index. BTW the  analysis of  fixed point is a possible framework  for consideration of  OP  question. But what  about  fixed point free and  orientation preserving case please see my comment  to  Andy Putman

@MikhailTikhomirov   I  do not get what do you mean "what about  2z"?

@AlexandreEremenko  I google searched  for  "Julia  set in Non  holomorphic  setting" but  I got  noting. Any way the OP question can generate  wide research  when  we  apply it to the  bijection case.

@MikhailTikhomirov  What feature you are interested in your  question? Local or  global one? If that is  global so I  suggest you  revise the  question replacing  M  with $\mathbb{D}$ or  $\mathbb{C}$.  Why  an unknown  M? The point  I  indicated to in my answer

Is there any chance for a topological characterization of holomorphic functions akin to the Thurston's dynamical criterion for holomorphic maps $\mathbb CP^1\to \mathbb CP^1$?

@Dmitry Korshunov: yes, people try to generalize Thurston's criterion for functions $\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}$, and this is a substantial area of research. I recall that even for rational functions, Thurston's result applies only to a small subclass of all rational functions.

To see why the second question cannot have a simple answer, it is sufficient to look at the local context near a fixed-point of a tangent-to-identity mapping, as Alexandre Eremenko suggests. By "a simple answer" I mean that a necessary and sufficient condition solving the problem posed by the OP is unlikely to be a (semi-)algebraic or (semi-)analytic condition expressed on the space of (germs of a) real-analytic diffeo.
On the one hand, an holomorphic parabolic germ $f(z)=z+az^{k+1}+\dotsb$ has its orbits organized along $2k$ petals, alternatively repulsive and attractive (Léau's theorem), and the space of its non-stationary orbits is the (non-Hausdorff) complex curve obtained by gluing $2k$ spheres near $0$ and $\infty$ to form a "necklace" consisting in $2k$ beads (Écalle–Voronin's theorem). In iterative dynamics, the gluing mappings are called "horn maps". Therefore, even at a topological level (i.e. allowing orientation preserving homeos $\phi$), the equivalence classes of orbits spaces of conformal diffeos is stratified by countably many strata (indexed by the number $2k$ of beads).
On the other hand, the dynamics of 2-dimensional tangent-to-identity real-analytic germs $g$ near an isolated fixed-point is much richer than that, in particular because the complexified diffeo $g_\mathbb{C}:(\mathbb{C}^2,0)\to(\mathbb{C}^2,0)$ has a curve of fixed-point that might remain unseen from the real plane, but still carries a lot of dynamical constraints. Papers on that topic appeared regularly in the last 30 years (see e.g. Bedford) and still do, and they all tend to show that orbits spaces (and their real slices) of parabolic 2-dimensional holomorphic germs are really complicated objects. For instance, in a recent preprint,
Klimeš and Stolovitch study a relatively tame and restrictive family of parabolic germs for which the space of orbits is more like an infinite necklace (i.e. with infinitely many beads and horn maps).
Germs near a fixed-point with irrational multiplier are probably a lot more difficult to fathom. And that's only the local question.

Yes local  analysis around  fixed points  and  periodic orbits is  a  complicated problem. but I wonder why OP uses the  Riemann surface  terminology (if he  is not searching for  global analysis?) With a  global view point existence  of two  different period for
a  diffeomorphism simply implies a negative  answer .  So my question: if there is no any  object to work(no periodic orbit) how can one apply your answer to the main question?

@Loic Treyssier: which question "does not have a simple answer"? The original question does have a simple (negative) answer. Are you trying to give some non-trivial characterization of germs which are conjugate to complex analytic germs, in terms of dynamics?

Again with a  global point of  view, let we have  an  algebraic  foliation of plane  whose  flow is a  complete flow(complete  algebraic  flow is classified  by  Chicone  and  Sotomayor). The  flow  $\phi_t$ is real analytic . Can one say that it is  conjugate to a global linear map?(az+b)

@Loic  I  think both local and  global version are exciting problems

@Loic but the  local version is  not a  new concept, is not a  new problem. On the  other hand globally thinking one may pose the  following:  are there sufficiently  high dimensional lie  groups of  analytic  diffeomorphism of the plane consist of  diffeomorphisms conjugate to bioholomorphis of  C or D? Motivation: The  bioholomorphism group is small!

@AlexandreEremenko: yes I was referring to the non-answered question: " If not, what are necessary and sufficient conditions for this to be the case?"

@Ali: let me kindly disagree with your last comment ;) I simply don't know how to characterize tangent-to-identity real-analytic germs which are locally analytically equivalent to holomorphic parabolic germs in terms of e.g. their Taylor coefficients or their functional properties (like solving ODE/PDE for instance) .

@LoïcTeyssier   +1  for  your very  informative  answer.  I   said  the  problem is not new but  I  did not say the problem is solved .  I meant generally  speaking the problem of analysis around fixed point in the Holomorphic  case is  an old problem. But here i  suggest the case no materials  we have, no fixed point no periodic orbit. My  precise question:  consider the usual  action of  $\mathbb{C}\rtimes \mathbb{C}^*$ on the plane via  $az+b$. Can one extend this  action in the  following  manner:

@LoïcTeyssier   A  complex  or  real Lie  group properly  contains $\mathbb{C}\rtimes \mathbb{C}^*$  which  extend the above mentioned  action in an effective  manner  by real  analytic  diffeomorphism each  conjugate to  some bioholomorphism  $az+b$. I  think this  is a  new  concept

@LoïcTeyssier Can one extend the dimension only by  1?!!  namely  a  holomorphic  Lie  group of dimension $3$ but  avoiding from trivial  action?

@LoïcTeyssier  To seek  non triviality  we  may impose the  extra  condition that the  group  $G \supset   \mathbb{C}\rtimes \mathbb{C}^*$  should not be a product or  a  semidirect product

@LoïcTeyssier  Any way  we just  talked  about  general  cases  what about a  particular (however  non injective case  $z\mapsto e^{\bar{z}} +z$ it is  fixed point free. is it conjugate to a  holomorphic map?

According to  existing informative  and interesting answers one gets that the  local dynamical behavior around fixed points or around periodic orbits may generates some obstructions for  being conjugate to  holomorphic  function.
But  I was thinking to the  case that we do not have any fixed point or periodic orbit.
I hope the  following would  be helpful as  a  partial answer to the  OP  question:
I  restrict the OP question to the case of  bijectve  maps.  We have  a  real  analytic  bijective  map $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$  and  we ask that is it conjugate to a  biholomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$?
A non trivial hyperbolic  invertible dynamics on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is  not  conjugate  to  any holomorphic diffeomorphism of the  plane
By  non trivial hyperbolicity I mean that  both  stable  and  unstable space are 1  dimensional  space(Non of them is  trivial)
Recall that  a  dynamical  system $(M,f)$ is a  hyperbolic  dynamic if  at each point $x$ of $M$ the  tangent space $T_x M$ is  decomposed to a  direct  sum $T_x M=T^s_x \oplus T^u_x$  such that both distributions  $T_x^s$ and $T_x^u$  are  invariant under $Df$. Further more the restriction of $Df$ to the  stable bundle $T_x^s$ is  a  contraction and the restriction to the  unstable  bundle $T^u$ is  an expansion.
As a  consequence the  hyperbolicity of  a  dynamic is preserved by smooth diffeomorphisms(smooth  change of  coordinate)
For  more information on hyperbolicity see the  following  two  linkes and  reference  therein:
Hyperbolic  structure
and
Hyperbolic  dynamics
